# Not getting data back from isomorphic-fetch (React/Phoenix)

Tags: reactjs, cors, phoenix-framework, fetch-api, isomorphic-fetch-api

I have a `create-react-app` on `localhost:3000` and a phoenix 1.3 server on `:4000`.  I am trying to set up JWT authentication between the two.

When I `curl` my server it works fine.

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"session":{"email":"me@example.com", "password":"password"}}' http://localhost:4000/api/v1/sessions

>>> {"user":{"id":1,"handle":"me","email":"me@example.com"},"jwt":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJVc2VyOjEiLCJleHAiOjE1MDYxNzQ2MzcsImlhdCI6MTUwMzU4MjYzNywiaXNzIjoiQXRoZW5hIiwianRpIjoiY2I5YjgyMDMtZjMxMi00YTE2LWIwOTItZjg4NDVlNmUzYzhiIiwicGVtIjp7fSwic3ViIjoiVXNlcjoxIiwidHlwIjoidG9rZW4ifQ.mg36_4Nj2tf26ey7c72rHnZKhQBlQZeBt1CSnsua44YYndt3i9ltPA1oq_WTp58f0f6X2KqioPlrdns2O5drgQ"}
```

The React side looks like this:

```
import React        from 'react';
import fetch        from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import { polyfill } from 'es6-promise';

const defaultHeaders = {
  Accept: 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};

function headers() {
  return { ...defaultHeaders };
}

...
fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/v1/sessions", {
   method: 'post',
  headers: headers(),
  body: JSON.stringify({session: {email: "me@example.com", password:"password"}}),
}).then(function(response){
  console.log(response);
  alert("Pausing so browser does not refresh");
})
```

When I make the `fetch` call, the server console outputs as though a `curl` request came in successfully.  However, nothing seems to happen in any function I put in fetch's first `.then()` clause.  I do not see an alert or a `console.log(response)`.

Initially I thought this was a CORS issue, but I installed cors_plug in phoenix and see the desired behavior on the server.  I also installed the [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) on Chrome.

Is there something I am missing about isomorphic-fetch?  (Or, alternatively, is there a more 'React' way to do this?)

Comment: Syntax looks fine. But, I'm surprised there is no output in the console. No console errors at all? What browser are you using? Can you verify in the developer tools, network tab, that your fetch request is actually being made, and is not returning with an error?

Comment: Also, add a second callback to the `.then` call to handle any additional errors.

Comment: The `Content-Type: application/json` request header your code is adding triggers the browser to do a CORS preflight OPTIONS request. So to emulate that in curl you need to do `curl -X OPTIONS -i -H 'Origin: http://localhost:3000' -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type' http://localhost:4000/api/v1/sessions`. If the server doesn’t respond to that with 200 & with 'POST' in the Access-Control-Allow-Methods response header & 'Content-Type' in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header, the preflight fails & the browser never tries your POST

Comment: @sideshowbarker   When I run that in curl, I get a 204 No Content.  From my browser, I get `Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:4000/api/v1/sessions", redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, …}`

Comment: The 400 (“bad request”) response the server’s sending back to the browser means the request the server received from the browser wasn’t what the server expected. So I guess you want to open the Network pane in your browser devtools, reload and then examine there the details of the POST request the browser’s sending—make sure it’s actually sending the `Content-Type: application/json` request header and that the body of the request looks like what you’re sending with curl

Comment: @sideshowbarker React refreshes the network tab when I make the request, which makes this difficult.  The server is logging `[info] Sent 201`, which I guess is a good sign.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Works great, turns out this was a classic CORS issue.  Feel free to post and I'll mark as correct.

Comment: @MarkKaravan—OK, added as an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Content-Type: application/json` header added by the code in the question triggers the browser to do a [CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). So to emulate that in `curl` you need to do:

```
curl -X OPTIONS -i -H 'Origin: http://localhost:3000' \
   -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' \
   -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type' \
   http://localhost:4000/api/v1/sessions
```

A comment above indicates the server responds to that with 204, which  shows the server’s at least configured to handle `OPTIONS` requests, so that part’s fine. But what’s not fine: the same comment indicates one response the server sends back to the browser is a 400 (“bad request”), meaning the request the server received from the browser wasn’t what the server expected.

So you can open the Network pane in your browser devtools, reload and examine the details of the `POST` request the browser sent—ensure it’s actually sent the `Content-Type: application/json` request header and the body of the request looks like what you’re sending with `curl`.